# Update multiple brushes when zooming

Tags: d3.js, zooming, brush

New to D3 here. I am attempting to combine [brush and zoom](https://bl.ocks.org/andrew-reid/33ed41fa918af88de8b447da3786de0f)(ex1) with [multiple brushes](http://bl.ocks.org/ludwigschubert/0236fa8594c4b02711b2606a8f95f605)(ex2).
The idea is that the user will be able to create multiple brushes on top of Ex1's focus chart to make annotations on the data. Which I am able to do. However, I am only able to update one(the first) annotation brush position on the chart after zooming using this on ex2's `zoomed` function:

```
.select("#brush-0").call(brushes[0].brush.move, lastSelection.map(t.applyX, t));
```

Where `t` is the zoom transform and `lastSelection` is the selection from the last brush that was created. Very hacky, I know, but at least behaves as expected.
I would like to be able to update all the brushes that are stored in the `brushes` array after zooming and panning in a way that can be called from the `zoomed` function. Help!

EDIT:
I have recreated the issue with my (flawed) solution attempt here: [jsfiddle.net/0pk8wce9/1](http://jsfiddle.net/0pk8wce9/1)

Comment: This KIND OF works:
`brushes.forEach(brushObject => {
var brushNode = document.getElementById('brush-'+ brushObject.id);
var brushSelection = d3.brushSelection(brush);
if(brushSelection != null){
focus.select.("#brush-" + brushObject.id).call(brushObject.brush.move, brushSelection.map(t.applyX, t)));}
});`
However, it produces a scale that does not correspond with respect to the actual zoom transform. Will try to reproduce in Fiddle asap

Comment: Please reply when you have the fiddle ready, then we can have a look

Comment: Please look at this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0pk8wce9/1/ Here I have reproduced my problem where I can update the scale an position of brushes but in a way that is does not correspond with the scale. Also I am not sure if using forEach is the correct way of doing this. Please help